# css and jquery straight children selector

Tags: jquery, css

Foe example given

```
     <div id="my_div">
        <div>aaa</div>
        <div>sss 
            <div id="this_is_not_straight_for_my_div">not straight</div> 
        </div>
        <div>ddd</div>
     </div>
```

How can select only straight childs for `my_div` element? Tell please this for `css` and for `jquery` also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#my_div > div` will target only direct children of `#my_div` (so not the one with the long id)

This uses the [direct child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) that hasn't got [IE 6 support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

`$('#my_div > div')` is the [jQuery equivalent](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

The jQuery selector WILL work on IE6

Comment: IIRC it does work on IE>=7, and IE6 is no longer officially supported.

Comment: @Kiyura Updated with reference to support table just before you commented :)

Comment: Also, to be clear, jQuery's selector is not the same and should work even on IE6.

Comment: @OTARIKI That is working, exactly as you mean it to. Div's inherit colours if they are not given their own, so assign one, like this. http://jsfiddle.net/Y4gKJ/1/ . Colour is something div's inherit, whereas margin or padding for example, they don't. So try that for proof of concept

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this:

```
$('#my_div > *')
```

Comment: And, to be clear, the css selector is inside the quoted string of the jQuery selector.